# Backspace function print('\b') not working

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple code from a Python textbook and it seems that '\b' does not work properly. I did a research and only found that it is a bug or it has something to do with ascii, which I dont understand at this level. Can anyone tell me how to delete the coordinates and rewrite them automatically every time the mouse cursor moves, instead of printing new coordinates endlessly? Or at least point me to what I'm missing here. So basically this code behaves as if this line:
print('\b'*len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
is absent.
Here is the code:

```
#! python3
# mouseNow.py - Displays the mouse cursor's current position.
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:    # Get and print the mouse coordinates.
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b'*len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

Comment: Actually \b just prints  blank space as many times as I wanted it to delete a letter. How do I write whitespace instead? I had tried \r and it does look a bit better (without dark-blue blanks), but the original ones are still not deleted.

Comment: Neither \b nor \r should delete anything. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to flush after the second print. They just move the cursor.

If \b doesn't work, what I would try next is replace both print with a single print(positionStr, end='\r', flush=True).

But really, the example in your question works in a normal terminal, so this is really about the terminal you're using and not a problem with python or pyautogui.

Comment: To remove the old line, print `\r` and then print `' '*len(positionStr)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It really runs normally in the terminal. I spent hours and didn't even try to run it in py.exe, because it didn't occur to me that the same code can work differently in the original editable file. (I still don't quite get why, but as a beginner I'm taking it as a fact and I can now fain go on learning).

Comment: "I still don't quite get why" - because backspace and carriage return are symbols used in interactive typing (which is terminal build for). File editors don't have any interactivity, so they just dump all characters which are inside the file. When you write to the file using `print()`, you cannot delete characters from file, just append new ones to the end, and `\b` `\r` are actually regular characters, so they're stored inside a file

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is normal. It is better to try it in Pycharm, VSCode or IDLE.
In VSCode, only `X` and `Y` change and are [not printed always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1PkQ.jpg) like IDLE.